# Making use of the serial data received via UART - a few concerns

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, embedded

So I have been finally able to send and receive data serially via usart, but now I'm thinking of getting something useful out of it.
One thing that I do plan on doing is maybe take in the input, provide a relevant output. So if the user types in "temperature", i'd send back a temperature value after reading off the sensor.
Another would be to turn on the led.

But I have a few concerns:

- I am specifying the length of the input that I expect from the user to my driver function, but what if the user types in more than the length? I started to see weird issues.

```
    if (pusart->handle->SR & USART_SR_RXNE) {
       pusart->rx_buffer = pusart->handle->DR;
       pusart->rx_buffer++;
       pusart->rx_size--;
    }
```

So RXNE is set upon the reception of each byte, but how do I deal with something like: "temperature status" than just a single char?

- `pusart->rx_buffer` points to the buffer stored in `main`. How do you keep track of the input that the user just typed in and not something that was previously inputted into the buffer? For e.g: buffer size is 20. When user types `temperature`, `buffer`'s first `12` (including `\r`) indices are already taken. Now user inputs `LED`. Now the subsequent `4` indices are taken.
  And you would only parse from index 12 to index 15 for `LED` and not previous data.
- Each character is stored in a specific index in a buffer. How does one parse efficiently?

Is circular buffer the solution where the `tail` would point to the index that will be the starting point of the latest input and `head` points to the first element? So for each input, I increment tail and head accordingly so both ends include the string that was inputted and can then parse the data? But from what I've seen, circular buffer works by moving the `head` when the element gets removed otherwise you continue incrementing `tail` (with some exceptions).

- How would the code flow look like for something where you listen to the input, and then do certain actions (similar to the idea discussed earlier)?

```
    rx_buffer[50];
    while(true) {
       usart_read();
       // if current input is "led", toggle led
    }
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a purely software question, not specific to embedded computing or engineering design.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be moved to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

> I am specifying the length of the input that I expect from the user to my driver function, but what if the user types in more than the length? I started to see weird issues.

The first solution I ever used was if too many characters were entered consecutively without a termination character, I would clear the entire buffer and send a message back telling the user they were entering in garbage.

> So RXNE is set upon the reception of each byte, but how do I deal with something like: "temperature status" than just a single char?

You can use interrupts per character to copy it into memory to buffer it. Or better yet, use a DMA to do the copying job from the UART receive register into memory for you.

Then you can parse it all at once in the main program loop. For example, an interrupt triggers when a termination character is received and the ISR sets a flag which is is read by main loop to start a parse. Don't parse directly in the interrupt.

> Each character is stored in a specific index in a buffer. How does one parse efficiently?

Look at the tokenizer functions in the C library. Or you can write your own...but that's really big task.

> Is circular buffer the solution where the tail would point to the index that will be the starting point of the latest input and head points to the first element? So for each input, I increment tail and head accordingly so both ends include the string that was inputted and can then parse the data? But from what I've seen, circular buffer works by moving the head when the element gets 
>   removed otherwise you continue incrementing tail (with some exceptions).

Before I had a circular buffer, I had a ping-pong buffer and for this every message was already self-contained in a linear buffer so when my code was this way I used pointers to directly manipulate and parse characters in the buffer.

Actually, that's a lie. At first I copied complete messages from the ping-pong buffer to a working buffer for parsing. But after I got things working I realized how wasteful it was to duplicate an entire message for no reason and modified things to use a pointer directly to the ping-pong buffer.

Afterwards I turned my ping pong buffer into a single intermediary linear buffer where messages were stacked inside it end to end. I added "read here next" pointers, "write here next pointers". I also had pointers for "this was the where the write pointer was when you started this read operation". There were also other routines that ensured that the "write here next pointer" was never allowed to step on the "read here next pointer". I also had routines that would determine whether the buffer was empty or full by comparing the positions and order of the "read here next" and "write here next" pointers. I ignored messages at the end of the buffer that would get cut off because this was an incremental step to a circular buffer.

The circular buffer was LOT trickier due to the wraparound and I wouldn't have been able to do it if I did not do the ping-pong buffer first. That is to say, 
it was tricky enough that I wasted a lot of time trying to apply the C-library tokenizer functions to characters that were not located sequentially in memory. I never did figure that out without writing my own tokenizer functions.

I really wanted to keep them in the buffer for parsing using pointers like I did before but ultimately I ended up having to copy the message being parsed (book-ended by termination characters) from the circular buffer  into a linear working buffer where I could apply the C-library tokenizer functions.

Other than this, the main things added to the sequential buffer to turn it into a circular buffer was making the read and write indexes wraparound.

Comment: I am using interrupts for each byte received as I mentioned, which I then write to the `rx_buffer` in `main`. I don't know if I should be parsing all at once rather than each input received. I could have used tokens but wouldn't they be more useful if you already have a buffer that's full of data ready to be parsed and is not being changed? if I get `Hello\r` at first, I parse it, fine, and then `World\r`, making it `Hello\rWorld\r`. it's more like you tokenize the first input, and then the pointer is pointing to `NULL` so even if you concatenate, it would still be `NULL`

Comment: @xyf It's your code but it sounds like a nightmare to me to constantly be jumping in and out of the same parse. You can parse one part of a buffer while it is being written to in another location as long as you know when to stop.

Comment: well, I have an idea in mind that I place on executing, which is to get the input, execute it accordingly, and continue doing so. The only way I can think of is to keep track of the starting index of the latest input and parse it till I see `\r` but not sure if there's a better way

Comment: also, regarding your comment about termination character, so instead of closing transmission upon `rx_size` going all the way to zero, I should also be checking for `\0` indicating the user is done typing in, which makes sense. So either `rx_size` goes to 0 or there's a `\0`

Comment: my bad. `\r` is what I meant

Comment: @xyf \0 is just the termination character for an array in a string. It's not anything that the user enters in to indicate they are done typing. Do you also mean for the user to type in \r everytime they are done a token? Wouldn't it normally be a whitespace to delimit tokens and then \r\n to denote termination? But yeah, you can parse from the beginning of wherever the entrance to the buffer is all the way to the termination character \r\n.

Comment: no. when you press enter, `\r` gets appended to the buffer along with what they typed which I can use to indicate they're done typing...